# Expose OnSelectedIndexChanged event in CompositeControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, composite-controls

If I have a `DropDownList` control that makes up part of a CompositeControl how can I expose the `SelectedIndexChanged` event to the consuming aspx page?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a much simpler way that is a direct pass through.

Try this:

```
    public event EventHandler SelectedIndexChanged
    {
        add { this.TargetControl.SelectedIndexChanged += value; }
        remove { this.TargetControl.SelectedIndexChanged -= value; }
    }
```

[Edit] Unless of course you need to inject custom logic.

Comment: I was using this method without success. My issue turned out to be a naming convention problem between my control property and my markup attribute. For others, remember that OnSelectedIndexChanged in markup will match to the SelectedIndexChanged property of your control.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what you do. First declare an event like this:

```
public event EventHandler SelectedIndexChanged;
```

Then, internally, hook up to the DropDownList's SelectedIndexChangedEvent. In your event handler do something like this:

```
        protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.SelectedIndexChanged != null)
            {
                this.SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e);
            }
        }
```

All you're really doing is wrapping the original event and re-raising it.

EDIT: See Brian Rudolph's answer. That's in fact a much simple way of doing it.